# DB2 Syntax Error in Java, Works Fine in SQL editor

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2

I have the following java code to create a prepared statement from the passed in connection. This is only a portion of the code and I've changed the name of the table for anonymity.

```java
private static final String preparedStatementSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE (STORE_ID,"
        + "BRAND_NAME,BUSINESS_DATE,HOUR,FCST_SYSSLS_AMT,FCST_USERSLS_AMT,FCST_SYSTRN_CNT,"
        + "FCST_USERTRN_CNT,ACTION_TIMESTAMP) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,(current timestamp))";

private PreparedStatement ps = null;

public TABLE(Connection con) throws SQLException{
    this.ps = con.prepareStatement(preparedStatementSQL);
}
```

When it runs the following line:

```java
this.ps = con.prepareStatement(preparedStatementSQL);
```

I get the following SQL error:

```java
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "HOUR" at line 1, column 67.
```

I copied the statement into my SQL editor (SQuirreL) and put in some made up values, and it worked fine (no syntax error!).

It is an IBM DB2 database.

I tried deleting the column names to just do:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,(current timestamp))
```

And it fixed the problem, but I have to have it use the (COLUMNS) VALUES (?... ) format.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `HOUR` is probably a reserved word, try `\"HOUR\"` inside your your String constant. And btw: `current_timestamp` doesn't need paranthesises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HOUR` *is* a reserved word in DB2.  The list is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_reservedwords.htm).

You should put double quotes (`"`) around it in the column list.

`TABLE` is also a reserved word.  I assume that you have a real table name there, though.

Comment: I tried that before and thought it didn't work because I got the same error. I realized now that when I put the quotes in there, the exception is getting thrown later in my test cases when I use dbunit to compare my output to a database snapshot I have in an xml file. Looks like dbunit is trying to do the same insert that I was to insert the rows in my xml file into a second in-memory database for comparison, and is running into the same error. Don't think this is going to be quite as easy of a fix...